# Amend Contract through Salesforce API call

Tags: rest-api

I need to integrate an external system to the Salesforce.

I was able to create Contract but the next step involves in Amending the Contract. i.e there is a Button called "Amend" which creates Quote lines once clicked. I need to do it through Salesforce API. I am new to Salesforce and I need help in how to achieve this.

Comment: After a lot of Googling I identified there is an API to do it - https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Developer-Guidebook/Public-API-Overview/tac-p/15429.

In the URL it shows about amending the contract, can someone help on how to use these API's